# Upgrading a managed package from patch to the next release version

Tags: patch

I have a managed package in production currently (4.1) and I am looking to release a patch for this version (4.1.1). In the near future, when we release a 4.2, can my customers upgrade from 4.1.1 to 4.2 just like any other managed package upgrade? 
I think yes but since this is our first patch I want to be certain that we wont run into any unforeseen issues in the future.

Comment: Yes. I used to work for an ISV and deployed patches quite often and never had any issues. Just follow the best practices. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/push_upgrade_best_practices.htm

Comment: As documented and in my experience, yes. The limitations on the changes you are allowed to make in a patch ensure that there is nothing extra introduced in the patch that could then be missing in the next non-patch version.

Comment: To piggy back on Kieth C. You have to ensure your patch changes make it into your current development effort so you don't end up overwriting a patch. Unless you are 100% certain that your development effort will not affect the area you are patching.